# how to connect to samba share consistently on el capitan

Tags: macos, smb

I have a file server which I can successfully and consistently connect to on android and windows. So I know the IP address and connection details. However when I try and connect using mac osx finder - connect to server or a third party utility it fails.

What do I need to do on El Capitan to get SMB shares working successfully in the sidebar of finder?

it just times out saying cannot connect - while my other devices all connect no problem.